# Where is the VS template for a .NET Core console app (or .NET 7) with C#?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022, .net-7.0

I must be missing something obvious.  I'm using Visual Studio 2022 (17.6.4).  I  want to whip up a quick console test app using C# and .NET 7.  I cannot find a project template for it.  I'm almost positive I've done this before.

I see a template for a console app using .NET Framework.  I see one using C++ (and Visual Basic and even F#) But nothing for .NET Core or .NET 6 or .NET 7.

Meanwhile I work on a .NET 7 app every single day so I though I had the components I need installed

I also have a template for a WPF app which will allow me pick .NET 7.  But no console app

Is there something else I need to install?

Comment: Do you mean this? https://i.stack.imgur.com/IEk0T.png Make sure you don't have any of the filters excluding it.  Its just called "Console App" but the difference is the platform tags.

Comment: Yes!  That's exactly what I mean.  Good to know I'm not losing my mind.  I am not seeing that.  No matter how I twiddle the filters

I think I'm going to try to repair my install

Comment: Before that, check to see in the installer for visual studio if you installed the .NET Desktop development toolset https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZBWE7.png  I would think you would have if you see the .NET Framework version.

Comment: Yes all of that is installed.  And additional components beyond.